# Understanding Happens-Before-Relationship

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Consider the following class:

```
public myClass {
    int a;
    Object obj;    //This object is not of class myClass nor of a subclass of it.

    void foo(int b){
        synchronized(this){
            print(a);
            a = b;
            obj.value = b;
            obj.bar();
        }
    }

    void bar(){
        synchronized(this){
            //Some code using obj here.
        }
    }

}
```

The Java documentations states:

> When a thread releases an intrinsic lock, a happens-before relationship is established between that action and any subsequent acquisition of the same lock.

Assume two threads T1, T2 and an object of myClass called myclass.

Now T1 calls foo, a short time after that T2 calls bar and eventually get's the lock and enters bar(). Correct me if wrong, but as far as I understand T2 see's changes done to variable a from T1.foo(b). How is it with changes done to obj? Consider this an arbitrary other object.

Is there an happens-before relationship guaranteed?

Comment: Your source is not really Java. `int Object obj` is meaningless, and if `obj` is `Object`, it doesn't have a `value` or a `bar()` method. You should clean up your example.

Comment: Sry for that typo, I tried to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: T2 acquires the lock that has been released by T1. So there's a happen-before relationship, and the writes done by T1 before releasing the lock are thus visible by T2 after it has acquired the lock.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility.

Note that it is about *memory operations such as reads and writes of shared variables*. Not only reads and writes of fields of the object being used as the lock.

Comment: It's very likely that a call to obj.bar() in my example will call itself other function which in turn might mutate other object etc. is this covered aswell? So when used as in my example T2 will see everything done by my function call of T1, of course only those changes in the synchronized block, without limitation?

Comment: So actually what I'd like to know is, just to be sure I understood you correctly, when a lock is acquired by A, released and acquired by B. B is able to see any changes to any objects/variables in our current JVM environment done by A while A hold the the lock?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: wow that's huge, in terms of what we get for so little code..thanks!

Comment: Actually, it will see all the changes made by A before it released the lock. Including those made before it acquired it, and not just while holding the lock.

Comment: Ah since statements in a program have a happens-before relation aswell and happens-before is transitive, right?

Comment: Or, to put it succinctly, locks have no idea what they lock.